# 404.0 error on remote web service, but not local on IIS

Tags: iis-6, asmx, http-status-code-404, localhost

I have a web service I have written and am trying to publish to a production server.  The strange thing is, when I pushed it on the server and set up a virtual folder for the service, it doesn't want to work when accessed from the Internet!

If I open up IIS 6 admin, look at the folder, right click on the .asmx file and select browse; it opens in Internet Explorer fine!  If i change the URL to the public URL name, it works ok, but only on the server.  If I try to access it from my desktop, I get a 404.0 error!  I know the file is there, it works fine on localhost on the server!

I'm pulling my hair out!  Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure the server you're working on is the production server?  could be something simple like that, getting ftp connections mixed up is easy.

Comment: positive.  I even tried via IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a stupid error on my part.  When i deployed the web service, i put it in it's own folder on the server.  I didn't check permissions on the folder though.  When accessing it on localhost, my logged in user had administrative privileges and could see the file.  Remotely, as anonymous, it couldn't.  Once i matched permissions to what wwwroot had, it worked fine.

- List item